# What exactly is session_start();

Tags: php

The title says it all, hoping to get an in-depth reply but for a beginners level so please none of that jargon!;) Thanks in advance!:)

To those who feel this is a duplicate, I could not fine a question directly related to this one, by all means please show me where and I will admit my mistakes!:)

The link provided does not answer my question I feel, please to point out if I'm wrong.

Comment: Have you looked at php's [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) documentation? It is pretty easy to read. If you have questions after checking that out, feel free to post them here.

Comment: http://www.php.net/session_start, you're welcome.

Comment: Have you read [the manual on PHP sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)?

Comment: it's a ritual to invoke right to store persistent data in `PHP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a `GET` or `POST` request, or passed via a `cookie`.

Read more here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Here is a tutorial on how to use sessions:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php

Comment: Thanks, the link to tizag was quite helpful, I like how they start of simple, will accept the answer when I can!:)